# double.parse returning a precision difference

Tags: c#

Why does `double.parse ("1833.35")` return value `1833.349999999999` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [switch to using a decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx) instead of a double if you need it to be absolutely correct. Decimal stores the number with a base 10 exponent.

There is no way to represent .35 exactly using a double or float.

Comment: yes decimal does the job, but i still do not understand what is the meaning of the base 10 into the.999999

Answer (score 6):

It's because floating-point values are represented in the machine with binary exponents, and 10 is not an even power of 2.  Thus, some base-10 fractions turn into repeating fractions when converted.

To illustrate, just work out how you'd represent 35/100 in binary.

Comment: ok, then does it means that there is no way to have the parsing done correctly?

Comment: @user96547 The parsing is done correctly, what matters is how you display it. Especially if you consider that .9 repeating is equal to 1.

Comment: Well, it's not that the parsing is *incorrect*, it's just that you cannot exactly represent 1833.35 in a binary format. It's doing the best it can :-)

Comment: @user96547 - the parsing is done correctly, just you can't represent 1833.35 directly in floating point. if you want to be sure, use the Decimal type.