# Double.Parse precision/Rounding issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have one column in database with datatype

> decimal(24,10)

Let suppose I have value like

> string d1 = "123.6666666666";

```
Double.Parse(d1)
```

**output in datacolumn** : 123.6666666700

I have used `Convert.ToDecimal(d1)` which gives output **123.6666666666**.

> Expected output :123.7000000000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [double.parse returning a precision difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190120/double-parse-returning-a-precision-difference)

Comment: @Magnetron Please check the question now.

Comment: Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(d1), 1)

Answer (score 4):

The output you got is because the precision of double and decimal values. What you actualy want is to round the number to 1 fractional digit, for that you have to use Math.Round, either with a double or decimal, according to your needs, like this:

```
Math.Round(Double.Parse(d1),1)
```

Or, if you need

```
Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(d1),1)
```

For more information about Math.Round, check the MSDN link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what is the precision of double and decimal?

Comment: @Mukund double: 15-16 digits; decimal: 28-29 significant digits. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/678hzkk9.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/364x0z75.aspx if you want to preserve the full value and only display 1 digit, you can use .ToString("0.#")